# How can I leave 'allowfullscreen' attribute as a boolean in CKEditor?

Tags: iframe, ckeditor, internet-explorer-11, html5-fullscreen

What I would like to do is leaving 'allowfullscreen' attribute itself without any value even ' ="" '.

ACF is in custom mode with iframe["allowfullscreen"], and it makes allowfullscreen attribute to ' allowfullscreen="" '. Wanna put this as a boolean itself, but CKEditor won't accept it without any value in it.

I'm using youtube link with iframe, and fullscreen function works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge but not in IE11. What I found till now is that IE11 only accepts 'allowfullscreen' , not with any value like ="", ="true", ="allowfullscreen" etc.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.